# Should I use a trailing slash when disallowing a directory in robots.txt?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, trailing-slash

I want to disallow crawling of a directory `/acct` in `robots.txt`    Which rule should I use?

`Disallow: /acct`  or  `Disallow: /acct/`

`acct` contains sub-directories and files both. What is the effect of a trailing slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `robots.txt` rules are all "starts with" rules, both of your proposed rules would disallow the following:

- `https://example.com/acct/`
- `https://example.com/acct/foo`
- `https://example.com/acct/bar`

However, the following would only be disallowed by the rule without the trailing slash:

- `https://example.com/acct`
- `https://example.com/acct.html`
- `https://example.com/acctbar`

`Disallow: /acct/` is usually better because there is no risk of disallowing unexpected URLs. However, it does NOT prevent crawling of `/acct`.

In most cases web servers redirect directory URLs without a trailing slash to add the trailing slash. It is likely that on your server, `https://example.com/acct` redirects to `https://example.com/acct/`.  If that is the case, it is usually fine to allow bots to crawl `/acct` with no trailing slash and see the redirect. They would be blocked from crawling the target of the redirect.

Comment: I have an angular application. /acct  shows the  Dashboard page which is sorta index.html.  From there user can go to   /acct/page1,   /acct/page2    and so on.   Is it important to have  a   url   as    /acct/     or    /acct    is  fine   from SEO perspective?  Days when a directory held bunch of static html pages are long gone.  Also if all my rest calls begin with /api  and if I want to prevent robots crawling it,  will     Disallow: /api  would be enough or /api/*  ?  Is /ap/  and /api/*  are the same ?

Comment: Using either `/acct/` or `/acct` is fine as long as you are consistent about it.  One should redirect to the other.  It's traditional to use the one with the slash, but that isn't a hard and fast rule.

Comment: `Disallow /api/` is better than `Disallow: /api/*`  By default rules are "starts with" rules. The original spec didn't allow wild cards at all in `robots.txt`.  Most clients still don't process wildcards. Only more advanced clients like search engine spiders can handle those.  At best a wildcard at the end is redundant.  At worst it will prevent the rule from being understood.

Comment: Just for anyone who stumble upon here,  I used nginx rule in https://serverfault.com/questions/597302/removing-the-trailing-slash-from-a-url-with-nginx       

location ~ ^(.+)/$ { return  301  $1$is_args$args; }    to remove the trailing slash site-wide